# Failure Sending Mail. Unable to connect to remote server. A socket operation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, smtp, gmail

So I'm trying to send an e-mail through VB.net code and I keep getting this error. I've disabled my firewall, and I can successfully send an e-mail when it's not getting the text from the textbox. I know that I have the right settings as it works when I send an e-mail with the body of 1 line.

```
Private Sub SendMessage(ByVal SmtpHost As String, ByVal SmtpPort As Integer, ByVal ssl As Boolean, ByVal SmtpUsername As String, ByVal SmtpPassword As String, ByVal mail_from As String, ByVal display_name As String, ByVal Send_To As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal Body As String, Optional ByVal Attachments As String() = Nothing)
        Using smtp As New SmtpClient
            smtp.Host = SmtpHost
            smtp.Port = SmtpPort
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(SmtpUsername, SmtpPassword)
            smtp.EnableSsl = ssl

            Dim message As New MailMessage()
            Try
                message.From = New MailAddress(mail_from, display_name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
                message.To.Add(Send_To)
                message.Subject = subject
                message.Body = Body
                If Attachments IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each attachment As String In Attachments
                        message.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(attachment))
                    Next
                End If
                message.ReplyToList.Add(New MailAddress(mail_from))

                smtp.Send(message)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine(ex)
            End Try
        End Using
```

Error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 0.0.0.1:465
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at EmailSender.Form1.Timer2_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: You didnt mention the error you were getting... Also please clarify this, "but when I type in the textbox it's not just one line, could that be it? How can I make it so it'll send the e-mail with multiple lines?" That doesnt make sense...

Comment: I changed the Smtp e-mail code and I still get the same problem, I updated the question with the error.

Comment: You have a timer doing this? ...

Comment: Yes, I have a timer doing this to see if it'd every work... However not even once has it worked with the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try
Dim mMailMessage As MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
Dim fromEmail As String = "<sender_mail_ID"
Dim fromPW As String = "<sender_password>"
Dim toEmail As String = "<Receiver_mail_ID>"
mMailMessage.From = New MailAddress(fromEmail)
mMailMessage.[To].Add(toEmail)
mMailMessage.Subject = "<Subject goes here>"
mMailMessage.Body = "<Message AKA Body goes here>"
mMailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure

Dim smtpClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpClient.EnableSsl = True
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
smtpClient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(fromEmail, fromPW)

smtpClient.Send(mMailMessage.From.ToString(), mMailMessage.[To].ToString(), mMailMessage.Subject, mMailMessage.Body)

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Do not forget to use :

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might not have any error. But this specific 'Failure Sending Mail' occurs if your Mail account not configured properly. You must allow access to third party or external application to use your mail's SMTP service. You can change that in Mail setting.

Change that and try. That might work.

Comment: I thought that was the reason also, as I remember having to do that in the past. I'll look around for it and post back with what happens.

Comment: Was is allow access to less secure apps? If so I have that turned on.

Comment: NO. You need not to do that. Just allow SMTP access. Which service you are using to send mail ? i mean like gmail or any other ?

Comment: I'm using Gmail yes sir

Comment: Than log in into you gmail account, go to settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP and you will have your settings. Just change them as per your requirements.

Comment: Both POP and IMAP are disabled, not sure if they're suppose to be enabled but how does that make SMTP work?

Comment: Yes you are right. Changing that wont change anything. Find SMTP access setting in Settings. Go to the link provided above.

Comment: I'll post back with what happens tomorrow since it's late.

Comment: Okay, I followed that link and did what it said and now it e-mail doesn't show up but I still get the messagebox saying it has been sent.

Comment: That means mail is being successfully sent. Now check you spam in case of mail sent there.

Comment: Checked spam and all the locations couldn't find it.

Comment: Posted another answer. I am currently using this code and its working fine.

Comment: Well I found it that the port 25, and 465 doesn't work as it won't go through on telnet. So the code worked fine, it was just my pc.

Comment: Thank you @user3329318 that was the trick for me too! Office365 smtp worked with port 587 per this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents. In my case I had everything laid out perfectly and what threw me off without realizing that I had privateinternetaccess application running in the background that prevented every attempt to connect to the server. Not cool :(